# Can I change the heap size for Groovy in Beaker notebook?

Tags: beaker-notebook

When I am launching Beaker notebook, can I change the heap size for Groovy? I'd like to customize this if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To customize the heap size, launch Beaker like this:

**beaker.command --plugin-option Groovy:-Xmx8g**

Or you can edit your [beaker.pref.json](https://github.com/twosigma/beaker-notebook/wiki/Language-Preferences) file, and get that configuration every time you run Beaker.